# Compile Audience option not available in Office 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I am learning the sharepoint from video tutorial. I was creating audience group using sharepoint 2013 in office 365. in the video tutor is using sharepoint 2013 on machine. I can create audience successfully. but, I want to compile audience, I was looking for compile audience option. but it is not there, while tutor video has option below view membership. I've attached image of dashboard also.

[image: Dashboard]

Comment: In the early O365 days it ran once a week and we had no option to recompile; I don't know what the current status is. Have you searched the Microsoft knowledge base?

Answer (score 1):

Based on my experience, the audience won’t function correctly on SharePoint Online sites until audience compilation is completed. Normally, the compilation of audiences runs once a week, and mostly it happens on every Friday or Saturday. But the exact time depends on the time zone you are in. 
For more information, please see the information about the timer job of the User Profile service application-audience compilation:
[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc678870(v=office.15).aspx][1]

Because Office 365 use the SharePoint Online which is hosted at the backend, as a service application level settings in a multiple-tenant environment, Microsoft is not able to compile the audience by ourselves and for one specific tenant at present.

Comment: I can confirm it is typically compiled once a week on Fridays coming straight from the mouth of an engagement with a PFE last week.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t have good news for you. 
While on premise you can access Central Admin and run this job manually, there's no this option in SharePoint Online .
Normally, the compilation of audiences runs once a week, and mostly it happens on every Friday or Saturday. But the exact time depends on the time zone you are in.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint on-premise has this option to compile the audience, as you can control the service job. In SharePoint Online, it is not permitted to control service jobs so at present the compile job runs at 01:00 every Saturday.